# Error: Could not resolve the package 'rxdart' in 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart

I created an example project inside a my flutter package and inside my example project i did:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  my_package:
    path: ../
```

`my_package` used `rxdart` and i received an error after run my example project

> Error: Could not resolve the package 'rxdart' in
>   'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart'.

I ran `flutter packages get` but the error is still here.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. To solve it follow these steps:

1. Kill your app if it's running
2. Run `flutter clean` in both your main project directory and your my_package directory
3. Run `flutter pub get` in both your main project directory and your my_package directory

Now when you build your app you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

- Check first, if you added `rxdart` package to your `pubspec.yaml` as shown below:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: ^0.24.1
```

- Run `flutter pub get`

Comment: How are you importing the package in your .dart file? Can you link your code?

Comment: 100%. I did it!